# How to use RestSharp in SSIS ScriptTask

Tags: c#, api, ssis, restsharp

I would like to achieve the same thing what am doing in the following post I had in SSIS Script task ?

[RestSharp :Getting null from the result.Data althouh at the time of debug result has JSON returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518988/restsharp-getting-null-from-the-result-data-althouh-at-the-time-of-debug-result)

I had issues registering RestSharp all in GAC please help!